# Unwanted strikethrough in Firefox website links

Tags: firefox, hyperlink, links

When viewing a webpage in Firefox, for example [superuser.com/q/1580804/581166](https://superuser.com/q/1580804/581166), links on the page are struck through (see screenshot).

[image: screenshot]

Notice the link in the question and the `share` link at the bottom.

I am using Firefox 80.0 (64-bit) and I only have 3 extensions installed, which are

- McAfee WebAdvisor
- SEOquake
- Adblock Plus

Adblock Plus was only installed recently and the problem was there before it was installed so it can't be that one causing it.

**NOTE:** Interestingly, the preview of this question whilst I am typing it has links underlined as they should be.

[image]

What is going on here?

How can I get the links to display as they should?

Comment: This looks like a CSS issue. Do you have any custom styles that might be added by your browser extensions?

I suggest you start by testing a page in incognito mode or with all your extensions disabled, then turning them on one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  It was with SEOquake browser extension.

SEOquake strikes through links which have `nofollow` attributed to them. Disabling SEOquake whilst viewing the site resolves the issue.

Comment: Well found - browser extension, yes?

Comment: Correct @chicgeek. It couldn't have been CSS with every website and I would have had no control over the CSS on this site anyway. :-)

Comment: Browser extensions can inject CSS, for example Stylish is made with this in mind to apply user styles over site styles. Regardless, I'm glad you got this sorted!